# My cat has a reddish brown eye and discharge from FHV-1. When should I worry?

Tags: cats, eye-disease

I know my cat has FHV-1.  It's currently flaring up, his eye is closed and when I peek in it's brown and red and discharging a bit.  He's had other much milder flare ups.  They all passed within a few days.

This one looks a bit worse.  It came on quickly, only having been a few hours now since I first noticed.

My question is:  **when should I worry?**  Will this just pass?

Comment: Please call or see a vet for advice. In questions of worries about the health of your pet, do not wait for strangers from the internet!

Comment: The point of asking on the internet is so that it queryable for others in the future.

Comment: Okay, but then you should tell us also, what your vet said about it. And if you got some advice how to act from the vet, you can answer your question also, to add your new knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Based off [this article](https://www.celestialpets.com/herpes-in-cats-how-long-does-a-break-out-last/) and my experience, it passes on its own;  usually within "a few days to a couple of weeks."

The article only ever mentions taking the cat to the vet if they are showing symptoms but don't have FHV.